# How to obtain the model values from a object having two models

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

In the following linq query var query is an object that contains two models.I am new to asp.net MVC4 ,How can we use the models in the object in my view class.
The var query is passed from controller to view by the ViewBag.Message concept. Please Help.

```
 var query = (from F in dataContext.flightobj
                     join FS in dataContext.flightscheduleobj.Where(FS => FS.FlightScheduleID == selectedID) on F.FlightID equals FS.FlightID
                     select new
                     {                             
                         F,FS
                     }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you dont combine your models and you dont write your query in view side..

```
public class UserView
{
public User User{get;set;}
public List<Messages> Messages{get;set;}
}
```

And then,

```
return View(new UserView(){ User = user, Messages = message});
```

In the view:

```
Model.User;
Model.Messages;
```

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions:

1. create strongly typed view, this way you can acces your model with Model. or @Model. After the . you will see your properties
2. not strongly typed, but then you dont have any intelisence from VS (and not strongly typed)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a specific view model and then pass that through to a strongly-typed view (where intellisense will be available to you), but if that isn't an option or you just don't want to do it that way, have a look [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views) for an explanation of using the dynamic way of doing things.

My recommendation would always be to go with a view model....makes your life easier. :-)

Answer (score -1):

I've found it quite difficult to use complex objects that have been passed into a view using the ViewBag, so I suspect that you'll be much better off passing var query into the view as a model instead of a ViewBag object.

You almost certainly can't explicitly use either flightobj or flightscheduleobj in your view, although you can use the columns from either model that appear in the join. You might want to write up a model just for use in the view, since doing so may help you get clear about what data will be available to the view and it will provide a nice strongly typed model to provide some intellisense as you work on the view.

Comment: Out of curiosity and a desire to improve my answers, why'd I get voted down?  Anyone know?